# How to redirect a customer to a page when register or login in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

I've created an override for AuthController, in specific the loginPage function. It will check if a customer has an Extension, if so then it will redirect to a specific page. This code only works when a customer is already logged in and directly goes to the account/login url.

What I want to achieve is, once a customer is logging in then the redirect statement should be checked. The same goes for a registration, once a customer is posting the registration form then a redirect should follow based on `$customer->hasExtension`.

How can I get this to work in AuthController and RegisterController?

```
public function loginPage(Request $request, RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        /** @var string $redirect */
        $redirect = $request->get('redirectTo', 'frontend.home.page');

        $customer = $context->getCustomer();

        if ($customer !== null && $customer->getGuest() === false) {
            if ($customer->hasExtension('X')) {
                $request->request->set('redirectTo', 'frontend.account.x');
            }
            return $this->createActionResponse($request);
        }

        $page = $this->loginPageLoader->load($request, $context);

        $this->hook(new AccountLoginPageLoadedHook($page, $context));

        return $this->renderStorefront('@Storefront/storefront/page/account/register/index.html.twig', [
            'redirectTo' => $redirect,
            'redirectParameters' => $request->get('redirectParameters', json_encode([])),
            'page' => $page,
            'loginError' => (bool)$request->get('loginError'),
            'waitTime' => $request->get('waitTime'),
            'errorSnippet' => $request->get('errorSnippet'),
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }
```

I've already tried adjusting the loginPage (GET), login (POST), accountRegisterPage (GET) and register (POST) function in the AuthController and RegisterController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `loginPage` will just return the response for the login form, it doesn't handle the login itself. What you want to do is either decorate the controller and replace/extend the original class with a compiler pass.

You'll need to call the original method that handles the login/registration. The tricky part will be to retrieve the then logged in/registered customer. You could get the token from the header and use it to rebuild the `SalesChannelContext` but that would be quite a bit of overhead.

The best I can come up with as of now would be to inject the `event_dispatcher` service, use a closure to capture the `CustomerLoginEvent`, call the original method and then use the captured event to get the customer.

Then use the same basic principe for the registration at `RegisterController::register`.

```php
public function login(Request $request, RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
{
        $loginEvent = null;
        $closure = function (CustomerLoginEvent $event) use (&$loginEvent) {
            $loginEvent = $event;
        };
        $this->eventDispatcher->addListener(CustomerLoginEvent::class, $closure);

        // if you decorated the controller
        $response = $this->decorated->login($request, $data, $context);
        // or if you replaced the class with a compiler pass
        // $response = parent::login($request, $data, $context);
        
        if (!$loginEvent instanceof CustomerLoginEvent) {
            return $response;
        }
        
        $customer = $loginEvent->getCustomer();

        if ($customer->getGuest() === false && $customer->hasExtension('X')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend.account.x');
        }

        return $response;
}
```